# Check if a textbox contains numbers only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to check if a textbox contains numbers only?

While googling I came across this. But I'm wondering if `isNumeric` can be used for this purpose or if there are more simpler ways of checking if a textbox has a numeric value.

```
var query = $('#myText').val();
if (parseFloat(query) == NaN) {
    alert("query is a string");
} else {
    alert("query is numeric");
}
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can check if the user has entered only numbers using `change` event on input and regex.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myText').on('change', function() {
        if (/^\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            // Contain numbers only
        } else {
            // Contain other characters also
        }
    })
});
```

REGEX:

1. `/`: Delimiters of regex
2. `^`: Starts with
3. `\d`: Any digit
4. `+`: One or more of the preceding characters
5. `$`: End

Regex Visualization:

[image]

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u4uecg8s/)

---

If you want to allow only numbers, you can use `input-number` and `pattern`

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d+" />
```

Comment: using `input type="number" pattern="\d+"`, how could I allow only two digits after decimal i.e. `10.99` but not `10.9999` ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy `\d+(\.\d{1,2})`

Comment: I can still add more than two digits after decimal point using above regex

Answer (score 4):

using pure JS regular expression

```
 var query = document.getElementById('myText').value;
 var isNumeric=query.match(/^\d+$/);
  if(isNumeric){/*...*/}else{/*...*/}
```

or using html5 control

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Answer (score 2):

There're many ways, you can use [**isNaN**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

```
 isNaN(VALUE);
```

You can also use regEx to verify numeric values.

```
console.log(/^\d+$/.test(VALUE));
```

Answer (score 2):

Jquery provides generic util method to handle this.
handles numeric/float/hex

```
$.isNumeric( value )
```

Try: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitg87/cfbyvr4d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the value of text box against the numeric regression to check if it contains numbers only or not, Like below code...

```
if($('#myText').val().match(/^\d+$/)){
// Your code here
}
```