# NumberTextBox allow only integer

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I need to make validation pass only for **integer** value in a `NumberTextBox`.

Using the following code, entering a decimal value in the `NumberTextBox` 54.454 wrongly validates.

I would like to know:

- How to validate only a `integer` values?
- Is it possible to avoid the user entering the `.`?

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lh3p0fb/7/

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox){
    new NumberTextBox({
          name: "programmatic",
        constraints: {pattern: '@@@'}
    }, "programmatic").startup();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323610/check-if-a-textbox-contains-numbers-only/30323668#30323668 might help you

Comment: useful link regarding  pattern property https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/quickstart/numbersDates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`places: 0`](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lh3p0fb/8/) as a [configuration](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/NumberTextBox#id4) option:

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function (NumberTextBox) {
    new NumberTextBox({
        name: "programmatic",
        constraints: {
            pattern: '@@@',
            places: 0
        }
    }, "programmatic").startup();
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question...Do you know if it is possible disabling entering the ./, on the control itself? Using NumberTextBox. I am aware is possible with some work around on event keydown, but I am not sure if it is supported my dijit itself. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: @GibboK, no problem, not too sure about that, ill have a look quickly

Answer (score 0):

I got a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input) and modified . please check if it solves your problem.

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );
      var regex = /[0-9]/;
      if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }
</script>`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is specifically for NumberTextBox in dijit..