# <asp:TextBox> should accept only numbers

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have created a textbox in asp as given below.Now my problem is Textbox should accept only numbers.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" runat="server" Text="" Width="100%" TabIndex="6" ></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I implement the function in Js file and call it in asp file.I have tried keypress event but error was raising as "keypress not an attribute of asp textbox".

I have tried Rangevalidators,RegularExpressionValidator also even though I was unable to get the requirement.

Please help me with this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30323668/2025923 might help you

Comment: Is `100.23` allowed or only integers?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate....

Comment: only integers it has to accept...@Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`CompareValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) with `Operator` set to `DataTypeCheck`:

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double" 
 ControlToValidate="txtRate" ErrorMessage="Value must be a number" />
```

These are the [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type(v=vs.110).aspx) you can check:

- String
- Integer
- Double
- Date
- Currency

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="TextBox1_FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server"
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" FilterType="Numbers">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a rangevalidator or a regularexpressionvalidator.
You have to set ValidationGroup and CausesValidation for the textbox.

See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_validators.htm for some examples.

You could also do validation clientside with javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRate" Type="Integer" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Text="Must be a number!"/>
```

Can swap out `Integer` for `Double` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I used a RegularExpressionValidator in a project to only accept numbers and decimals.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RepRateRegExVal" 
       ControlToValidate="repRateTxtbox" 
       ValidationExpression="^\d*\.?\d*$"
       runat="server" 
       Display="Dynamic" 
       CssClass="validator"
       Text="Repetition Rate must be a valid number">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If you want to only accept one place after the decimal change the expression to "^\d*.?\d$"

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CheckNumeric(e) {

            if (window.event) // IE 
            {
                if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8) {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    return false;

                }
            }
            else { // FireFox
                if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) & e.which != 8) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }

    </script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" runat="server" Text="" Width="100%" TabIndex="6" onkeypress="CheckNumeric(event);"></asp:textbox>
```

[source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/306192/Text-box-to-accept-only-number)

Comment: Already I have tried this,but it was showing an error "onkeypress is not an attribute of  textBox"...How can I solve that issue..

Comment: You should be able to compile and run the code above. The compiler will create "input" from textbox and everything will be ok

Answer (score 0):

you should be use ajaxtoolkit to do that

```
 <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ValidChars="yourcharallow" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="yourTextBox" ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```